# Unable to Retrieve List of Azure DevOps Check Configurations Using the REST API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to use this [ADO REST method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/check-configurations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#resource) but get a 400 (bad request) response. It complains that the resourceType and resourceId URL params are missing.

Yet, the documentation says that those parameters are optional. I, in fact, cannot call with those parameters since I do not know their values yet. I've tried with api-version 6.0, 7.0 and 7.1 all with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you could use `environment` as `resourcetype` and `environmentID` as `resourceID`. I requested with a environment with approval check and get the result below.
[image]